# How do i get an invoice section using azure.resourcemanager.billing sdk library

Tags: .net, azure, azure-resource-manager, billing

I want to be able to use c# to retrieve an azure invoice section using the azure sdk library (azure.resourcemanager.billing) in order to recreate this powershell method

`$token = Get-AzAccessToken
$request = @{
Method = 'PUT'
Uri    = "https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/$($billingAccountName)/billingProfiles/$($billingProfileName)/invoiceSections/$($invoicesectionname)?api-version=2019-10-01-preview"
Headers = @{
"Authorization" = "Bearer $($token.Token)"
"Content-type" = "application/json"
}
Body = '{"properties": { "displayName" : "Test"}}'
}
Invoke-RestMethod @request

```
$invoiceSection = Get-AzInvoiceSection -BillingAccountName $billingAccountName -BillingProfileName $billingProfileName | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Test"}`
```

I know this can be done using powershell and using the rest api but i want to use the azure sdk library.

I have tried using the azure.resourcemanager.billing library as the previous library is now marked as deprecated but i cannot find the right methods to use